# How many levels does the facebook comments support

Tags: facebook, comments

I know that Facebook supports nested comments and replies, but I'm unable to find information either on Facebook or elsewhere on how many levels it could be.

Could someone share if they know the answer or any link that has it?

*This is for an application I'm building to capture and store Facebook comments natively.*

Answer (score 1):

Just one level of nesting, I think. Atleast that's what it is for now:

[image: FB Nested Replies]

Source: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10200614071048741